# Disabling the Microsoft Windows 10 Windows Store

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, windows-store-app

How can one safely disable - or preferably uninstall - the Microsoft Windows 10 "Windows Store" that came preinstalled on my system?  I have little or no use for the 370 files in 102 folders that are occupying 104 MB on my C:Drive which is 78% full. If I need anything from Microsoft, I can go to Microsoft on-line to look at things I might need.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove it using PowerShell.
First, run `Get-AppxPackage` and locate the one with the name `Microsoft.WindowsStore`. Copy its `PackageFullName`. Now, run `Remove-AppxPackage -Package [Paste PackageFullName Here]`.

A quick warning though: it may be difficult to restore the Microsoft Store after it is removed. Make sure you actually want to remove it. If you are running low on disk space, consider instead running `cleanmgr` or for even more options and to scan and clean multiple drives at once, `cleanmgr /sageset:65535 /sagerun:65535`.

Sources: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/get-appxpackage?view=win10-ps

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/remove-appxpackage?view=win10-ps

https://www.howtogeek.com/256594/how-to-enable-hidden-options-in-windows-disk-cleanup-tool/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using non Windows home version, we could run the command line below in powershell script as administrator to uninstall store for all users.
Get-AppxPackage -allusers *windowsstore* | Remove-AppxPackage